# AppleScript change Terminal ProcessArgumentsInTitle boolean

Tags: terminal, applescript, profile

I want to change a specific terminal setting called `ShowActiveProcessArgumentsInTitle` to false.

```
tell application "Terminal"
    set ProfilesNames to name of every settings set
    repeat with ProfileName in ProfilesNames
        set title displays file name of settings set ProfileName to false
    end repeat
end tell
```

output
`Terminal got an error: Can’t set title displays file name of settings set "Grass" to false.`

Comment: A settings set doesn’t have a `title displays file name` property, that is a property of a tab.

Comment: @red_menace I know ShowActiveProcessArgumentsInTitle that is in the plists exists in AppleScript but it's not in the dictionary. setting it to a different profile with ShowActiveProcessArgumentsInTitle value of false works but the individual option I cannot find

Comment: Which property list has `ShowActiveProcessArgumentsInTitle`?  Is this an added key?

Comment: @red_menace it's in the plist as an option. I can't find it in the dictionary but applying it to another profile with having that in the plist of the profile does change the setting via AppleScript

Comment: A key in a settings property list wouldn’t necessarily have an equivalent scripting term (I don't see anything like that in the Terminal.sdef file).  If this added key is in a settings file to be imported, System Events or some AppleScriptObjC can manipulate property lists.

Comment: @red_menace changing the tab's current settings to another profile's current settings changes that value so I know it's possible I just don't know how. if there is no scripting term then how is it working the terminal applies more terms then AppleScript when changing a settings set?

Comment: That would be internal to the app.  Not all preferences or settings are exposed as a scripting term, it is up to the developer as to what they provide.  This appears to be the _Preferences > Profiles > Window > Arguments_ preference; since profiles can be imported they probably didn’t bother with it.

Comment: Then how does changing the settings set to a different set change something that the script doesn't have access to?

Comment: A script only has terminology that the application developers provide (if any), and doesn't necessarily include all application and preference items.  Terminal can import/export settings profiles independent of any scripting.

Answer (score 0):

simply goto terminal setting area and change profile

[image]

Comment: point of doing it is programmatically